# How to constrain users to select dates beyond today's date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 with options API.

Given [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-kasehp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue), I would like to know how I can set `:max` value to a `date-picker`. I set the `:max` to `new Date()`, but  I can still select dates beyond today's date.

Comment: If you're using vue3 as you say, then dont' tag spam vue2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `template` use `:max="maxDate"` then in your `script` do the following -

```
data() {
    return {
      maxDate: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0], // Set the max date to today
    };
  },
```

I have fixed it at https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-um9bae?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue

Note the screenshot below shows future dates as disabled

[image: image shows the fixed behaviour in date picker]